# paper-listbox does not have a required property

Tags: polymer-1.0

We are using the paper-listbox to select multiple records, we want to make sure at least one is required, and reacts similar to other polymer elements. Is there a common way that people mimic this? Any examples would be helpful.

Comment: `paper-listbox` does have a `selected` attribute. You could use this to see if an option has been selected or not.

Comment: I am using that to see if it is selected or not, but what do you use to show the error message similar to how paper-input works. If I try to use a paper-input the input field shows up....and if I make it enabled = false, the opaqueness  changes, and the input line still shows up, but not enterable (of course). But how would I hide the input line? I know I would need to change the opaqueness for enabled=false.

Comment: i used an iron-label instead and set the color to red, and used your .selected option as a check and showing/hiding the label... kind of janky, but until there is a 'required' option on the listbox section or someone has a built in solution of some kind. I won't close any of this as being answered.